# why facebook javascript login stopped working

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk

I have been using fb javascript sdk for some time now, to login users via my mobile web app. it worked great until about 2 weeks ago, as far as I could tell. Now, instead of redirecting me back to my web page, it shows me a blank page. When I debug using chrome's javascript console, I see some file being returned called "permission.request" or something like that, and that's it.

AFAIK I did not change anything.

My js code is:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
    appId: '#############',
        channelURL : options.webBaseUrl + 'channel.php',
        status : true,
        cookie : true,
        xfbml : true,
        oauth : true
});
```

and later, to login:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
    }, {
        scope : 'user_birthday, email, publish_actions',
    redirect_uri: '<my web page url>'
    });
```

I see the login page correctly, enter user/pwd, click "login", and then get the blank page.

My app is not in sandbox mode, the domain name is correctly configured for web & mobile web, it worked fine without apparent changes until recently...

Any ideas?
Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Chrome? if so, check your privacy settings. If third party cookies are disabled, all kinds of js snippets on a website will break.